# Cloning JPA entity including value annotated with spring's createdBy

Tags: java, spring, jpa, audit

I've got the following super class (abstract)

```
public abstract class AbstractAuditEntity {
  @CreatedBy
  private String createdBy;
}
```

I have several objects in my database. Now I want a method to clone a specific object and all its attributes including createdBy. I can set any String to this value, but the value is reset to the username currently authenticated before it gets persisted to database.

How do I prevent spring/jpa from overriding my createdBy field when it's already filled?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this seams to be impossible.

In the AuditingEntityListener the @PrePersist method looks like:

```
@PrePersist
public void touchForCreate(Object target) {

    Assert.notNull(target, "Entity must not be null!");

    if (handler != null) {

        AuditingHandler object = handler.getObject();
        if (object != null) {
            object.markCreated(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the AuditingHandler:

```
public <T> T markCreated(T source) {

    Assert.notNull(source, "Entity must not be null!");

    return touch(source, true);
}
```

Because of the second paramter that is true it will always set the createdBy field:

```
private Optional<Object> touchAuditor(AuditableBeanWrapper<?> wrapper, boolean isNew) {

    Assert.notNull(wrapper, "AuditableBeanWrapper must not be null!");

    return auditorAware.map(it -> {

        Optional<?> auditor = it.getCurrentAuditor();

        Assert.notNull(auditor,
                () -> String.format("Auditor must not be null! Returned by: %s!", AopUtils.getTargetClass(it)));

        auditor.filter(__ -> isNew).ifPresent(foo -> wrapper.setCreatedBy(foo));
        auditor.filter(__ -> !isNew || modifyOnCreation).ifPresent(foo -> wrapper.setLastModifiedBy(foo));

        return auditor;
    });
}
```

But as this seems to be an interesting feature you should go ahead and open a future request:
https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA/issues/DATAJPA-1397?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Yes, I saw the touchAuditor-Method. So the only way around this issue (by now) is to persist objects directly to database without jpa, right? Nevertheless, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes or you create your own JPA Listener and set the user.

Answer (score 0):

I created a feature request for DataJPA, but I don't know, when (if) it gets resolved.

Until then, I save the entity first and change the createdBy with native SQL. I won't mark this as accepted answer.

```
public interface EntityRepository {
  @Transactional(propagation = NESTED)
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "UPDATE entity_table SET created_by = ? WHERE id = ?", nativeQuery = true)
  void updateSignalRequestCreatedBy(String createdBy, long signalRequestId);
}
```

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)
[DataJPA-Request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1401)